# Why do all the generated Tor v3 vanity addresses end with "d"?

Tags: onion-routing, onionaddress

Recently I noticed that all the V3 addresses end in "d". Some examples from Ahmia.fi search results ("Tor" was the search query):

1. 2gzyxa5ihm7nsggfxnu52rck2vv4rvmdlkiu3zzui5du4xyclen53wi**d**.onion
2. pzhdfe7jraknpj2qgu5cz2u3i4deuyfwmonvzu5i3nyw4t4bmg7o5pa**d**.onion
3. rzuwtpc4wb3xdzrj3yeajsvm3fkq4vbeubm2tdxaqruzzzgs5dwemla**d**.onion

To make sure the story is correct, I made another test using mkp224o for creating custom V3 addresses (in this example I've generated addresses starting with **test**):

[image: All V3 addresses ending with d]

As another interesting result two ending letters as:

1. ad
2. id
3. yd
4. qd

Then I checked Tor Spec for v3 in here:
https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/main/rend-spec-v3.txt. This is the exact copy of section 6 (Encoding Onion Address):

> 6. Encoding onion addresses [ONIONADDRESS]
>
> The onion address of a hidden service includes its identity public key, a
> version field and a basic checksum. All this information is then base32
> encoded as shown below:
>
> ```
> onion_address = base32(PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION) + ".onion"
> CHECKSUM = H(".onion checksum" | PUBKEY | VERSION)[:2]
>
> where:
>   - PUBKEY is the 32 bytes ed25519 master pubkey of the hidden service.
>   - VERSION is a one byte version field (default value '\x03')
>   - ".onion checksum" is a constant string
>   - CHECKSUM is truncated to two bytes before inserting it in onion_address
> ```
>
> Here are a few example addresses:
>
> ```
>   pg6mmjiyjmcrsslvykfwnntlaru7p5svn6y2ymmju6nubxndf4pscry**d**.onion
>   sp3k262uwy4r2k3ycr5awluarykdpag6a7y33jxop4cs2lu5uz5sseq**d**.onion
>   xa4r2iadxm55fbnqgwwi5mymqdcofiu3w6rpbtqn7b2dyn7mgwj64jy**d**.onion
> ```
>
> For more information about this encoding, please see our discussion thread
> at [ONIONADDRESS-REFS].

All the examples are ended with **d** as I made them bold!

The documentation exactly says that:
***onion_address = base32(PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION) + ".onion"***

Therefore, base32 of "PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION" is always ending with **d**? Or **ad**, **id**, **qd**, and **yd**?

I also checked https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2017-January/011816.html and https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2016-December/011734.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how the base-32 conversion works out when the last byte is `0x03` (the version byte). For example, see the following base-32 conversions:

```
0x0000000000 = AAAAAAAA
0x0000000003 = AAAAAAAD
0x0000000103 = AAAAAAID
0x0000000203 = AAAAAAQD
0x0000000303 = AAAAAAYD
0x0000000403 = AAAAABAD
0x0000000503 = AAAAABID
0x0000000603 = AAAAABQD
```

In base-32, each 5 bits are mapped to a letter. The last byte (8 bits) is `0x03 = 0b00000011`, so the last letter will take 5 of those bits (`0b00011` is `D`), and the 3 other bits `0b000` go towards the second last letter. So for the second last letter, there are only 2 bits that can change, so there are only 4 possible letters for the second last letter (`0b00000` is `A`, `0b01000` is `I`, `0b100000` is `Q`, and `0b11000` is `Y`). For the bytes `0x0000000103`, the last 10 bits are `0b0100000011`. Of those 10 bits, the first 5 `0b01000` (decimal 8) map to `I` and the second 5 `0b00011` (decimal 3) map to `D`.